# Powering multiple LED strips with one power supply via termina connectors

Tags: power-supply, led-matrix

I bought a power supply so I can start experimenting with larger arrays of LED strips at home (I was previously using a wall wart with a small display).  The power supply provides 40A at 5V, however, the power supply only has one + and one – terminal.  How can I safely split the current to multiple strips?  I am looking at terminal connectors:

[http://www.amazon.com/Blue-Sea-Systems-Circuit-Terminal/dp/B000K2K6L6/ref=pd_bxgy_200_3?ie=UTF8&refRID=0HDQC12FCR3V0GJ967X](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000K2K6L6)

but I only see them rated for 30A at maximum.  I would feel better if they were rated much higher than 40A.  Somebody told me I could daisy chain them together but it seems like I would still need to pass 40A through the first one.  Would it be better to use a bus bar?  Also, can you recommend a fuse?

Comment: Be careful with the wires as well. You'll probably want 10AWG out of the supply or even 8AWG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With that terminal strip you have 12 *individual* connection points. You really need a bus bar like this:

http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/like/310173026317?adgroupid=13585920426&hlpht=true&hlpv=2&rlsatarget=kwd-131843267586&adtype=pla&ff3=1&lpid=122&poi=9045629&ul_noapp=true&limghlpsr=true&ff19=0&device=c&chn=ps&campaignid=207297426&crdt=0&ff12=67&ff11=ICEP3.0.0-L&ff14=122&viphx=1&ops=true&ff13=80

For fuses, I suggest you look at automotive blade fuses. These are affordable and rated to 40A and more.

Comment: Great, thank you.  Just to be clear, I would need two of these, right?  I would connect the first one to the positive terminal of the power supply and connect it to the + terminal on each of the strips.  The other bar would be connected to the - terminal and then to the GND terminal of each of the strips.

Comment: Yes you need 2. You may be able to find 2 already in a box with fuses if you look for marine or automotive power distribution boxes.